# Python HTTP server wfile image in html

Tags: python, html, css

I'm trying to write an image with

```
self.wfile.write(bytes(img.read()))
```

and it's working fine when I have `self.send_header('Content-type','image/png')`

but I need `'Content-type','text/html'` for other things that I do.
I tried

```
self.wfile.write(bytes("<img alt='Embedded Image' src='data:image/png;base64," + img.read() + "/>", "utf8"))
```

and I'm getting

> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: Do you want to include the images inline, with base64 encoded strings [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)? I can't imagine that it would work otherwise

Comment: `src=` expects link to file - ie. `src="http://example.com/image.png"`, or image bytes in base64.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I updated my question.